# How do I get my bot to transfer to a live agent?

Tags: liveagent, einstein, bots

I have live agent set up with omni channel routing. The default service channel for live agent is set up for live chat transcripts.
I have presence status associated with live chat transcripts.
I have a queue with live chat transcript as supporting object.
I have a routing configuration associated with the queue.

When I try to transfer to agent, the request doesn't turn up in the omni-channel widget in the live agent console. I'm set to online.

There's a message in the bot chat window 'We're transferring your chat to another agent.' but it never transfers.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add your agent to the same queue of snap-in. To check it, switch to classic, goto setup > Chat Button >  >> Scroll Down to queue associated > Add your user there

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dialog, that contain 2 steps.
Name if 'transfer to agent'.

On the new dialog. First step is a message and 2nd step select of type "transfer to agent".
See below image

[image]

Then any the dialog that you need, just point to this new dialog.

Comment: How the bot will know which Queue it has to transfer the Chat?

Comment: That is an awesome question.. Look forward for the answer.. 

But sorry I cannot answer that.
My bot only has one queue and one deployment..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all ,taking you time and responding on this.Issue has been resolved by Adding Omni-Channel to the Console App,and added Omni-Channel component to the app that we have created. Confusion happen on the Chat we have received is different one,and Omni-channel component is different.